# Trying to find the value of corresponding range of cells that contain dates, but only interested in the date is TODAY

Tags: excel

So, I have a range of monthly dates that span several years. Then I have a dollar value in the next cell lets call it A1:B100. I want to find the cell in B that corresponds with today's date. What I've used that works in finding the correct date is: AND(MONTH(a1)=MONTH(TODAY()),YEAR(a1)=YEAR(TODAY())) I just need to put it in a lookup function that spans the date range, but I'm stumped
Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These functions look for the value in b that matches today's date and then pull in the value from a. xlookup has an easier syntax, but you may need index/match if you don't have the newest version of excel.

`=INDEX(A1:A5,MATCH(TODAY(),B1:B5,0))`

`=XLOOKUP(TODAY(),B1:B5,A1:A5)`

Edit: I re-read your post, and if your data in a is by month (ie 1/1/2021, 2/1/201), just make sure it is in order, and change the match type to less than. If your data is in a different format, please post a screenshot of your data.

`=INDEX(A1:A8,MATCH(TODAY(),B1:B8,1))`

`=XLOOKUP(TODAY(),B1:B8,A1:A8,,-1)`

Comment: Well this sort of works.  I guess I was thinking way too hard on what the formula might be but getting back to sort of... I don't have the updated version so I used index. The 0 at the end of the function brought back a N/A, but 1 brought back the value of the cell above which corresponded with the month before. That happened to me before when I was using the aforementioned AND formula but I used it as a conditional formatting to highlight the month. Now the problem, in both instances I had to add 30(days) to the formula. I can't for the life of me figure out why.

Comment: This article does a good job explaining how the "less than" or the 1 in the formula works. If you need to add 30 days, add it right after the today() portion. You might need to be adding them if your dates are the last day of the month (ie 1/31/21, 2/28/21 instead of 1/1/21,2/1/21). If that is the case, you sort them in the reverse order and use the greater than (-1) in the formula. Article: https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-match-function

Comment: they are the last days of the month.  Good call  TY